# New root page in wagtail

Tags: internationalization, translation, wagtail

I want to change the Root page in Wagtail.

1. I have deleted the default home page
2. Created another page assigned "home" as slug.
3. Created a template my_page_name_home.html

But I am getting 404 all the time when I try http://localhost:8000/. Do I have to change the urls.py patterns?

I am doing this because of Wagtailtrans add-on. In order to work i have to redirect away from the homepage to my new page ot type *TranslatableSiteRootPage*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go to Settings -> Sites in the Wagtail admin, and add a site record to associate 'localhost' to your new homepage. (A site record for this exists on the default installation, but this would have been deleted when you deleted the default homepage.)

Comment: Wagtail beginner here, this is way more complicated than I would expect. I did the same thing as OP and the new home page never shows and always 404. Is this something said in doc that we need to add site record to bring the new home page back online?