# How To Programmatically Set Up Wagtail Root Page For Tests Utilizing The StaticLiveServerTestCase Suite

Tags: wagtail

This question is similar to [another question here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920803/new-root-page-in-wagtailt) .

I am in the process of adding tests to my wagtail site utilizing [Django's StaticLiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase). Below is an example of the code base I have at hand:

```
class ExampleTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_example_test(self):
        self.assertContains("Contact Page", self.browser.content)
    [...]
```

So when I run this test with `python manage.py test`, the test fails because I there is a 500 error. **Please recall that I am using wagtail and NOT Vanilla Django alone. I am also using Django's Site framework as opposed to Wagtail's Site framework as allauth only allows for usage with Django's Site framework.**

After applying the `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` to the test like this:

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class ExampleTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    
        def test_example_test(self):
            self.assertContains("Contact Page", self.browser.content)
        [...]
```

The test still fails as the page that is being loaded is the wagtail default page.

My question is, how do I set up another page as the root/default wagtail page such that when a request to **localhost:8000** [or any other port number given by the test server] is being made to the home page (i.e. **http://localhost:8000/**), I see that new page instead of the wagtail default page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `StaticLiveServerTestCase` creates a new [temporary] "test" database [**including running `migrations` and `migrate`**], wagtail literally resets all sites and pages back to it's initial state after initial `wagtail start [mysite]` command.

This means that if you have any other `Page` that you would like to be the root page, you will have to hard code the instruction to do that.

Below is a way in which this can be achieved.
**It is advisable to set these instructions within the `setUpClass` method of a class — usually a `class Main()` class where other test classes can inherit from; thereby encouraging D.R.Y**.

```
class Main(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(Main, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.root = Page.objects.get(id=1).specific
        cls.new_default_home_page = Index(
            title="New Home Page Index",
            slug="index",
        )
        cls.root.add_child(instance=cls.new_default_home_page)
        cls.site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
        cls.site.root_page = cls.new_default_home_page
        cls.site.save()
        cls.browser = Chrome()
```

Now my test classes (wherever they are) can inherit from this class and get the entire new home page setup instantly. For example:

```
# ExampleTest() inherits from Main() for ease of Wagtail Page setup: avoiding repetition of setUpClass().
class ExampleTest(Main):
    def test_example_test(self):
        self.assertContains("Contact Page", self.browser.title)
    [...]
```

Hope this helps someone out there someday.
**THIS SOLUTION IS VALID FOR: `wagtail==2.7.4`.** anything above this version isn't guaranteed to work as wagtail's code base dictates. However, it's very unlikely that this wouldn't work.